# Recovery data from nexus 5

Tags: adb, nexus-5, data-recovery, fastboot, images

I have a nexus 5 that give me a Black screen when i unlock it with sign-code.I can't utilize it but i have to recovery my data.I thought to install an update image with adb sideload to see if my phone restarts to work well and recover my data but I don't know if the update images wipe my data.Do update images wipe my data.Are there other methods to recover my data?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your launcher (home screen) is acting up. Turn on USB Debugging if you haven't (go to Settings from the notification bar), then `adb install` another launcher from your PC. After that press HOME and select what's installed.

Don't try updating stuff yet - there are ways to recover even if the above fails (though more complicated).

Comment: I can't access to the operating system.After I insert the sign the screen become black and I can do nothing:(I tried to do that but I can't...

Comment: I can't access the operating system...i tried to flash partitions from fastboot but flashing them my data will be erased...i have adb not enabled and I tried also to wipe cache partition but nothing...

Comment: I also thought to wipe my phone and then use a program to recover wiped data...I don't know what to do...

Comment: [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156684/ota-images-for-nexus-5) - not a good idea to double post, man. You should just edit this question to reflect updated details (which also bumps your question to the top), or you can just remove this question if it's no longer relevant. Either way, since @Firelord has already provided the info you need now, I'm out.