# Ota images for nexus 5

Tags: adb, stock-android, fastboot, nexus

I want to update my nexus 5 with an ota image because it freezes after I unlock it with the sign code and I can't access the os.So I want to update my system with adb sideload and an ota image that I download directly from Google to see if the problem will be solved.I don't want to erase my data so my question is:Does a flash of an ota image through adb sideload wipe my data?

Answer (score 1):

Google has noted [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/ota):

> [Manually updating your Nexus device using OTA binary image files] has the same effect of flashing the corresponding factory images, **but without the need of wiping the device**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

On the contrary, by OTA update, if you meant incremental platform/system updates, then even so, user data would not be wiped out.

User data would also not be wiped out if the [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) files are flashed manually (not via the included script) and *userdata* partition is skipped from flashing.

**Note:** It is my assumption that the question refers to *data* as everything created or added by the user (directly or indirectly - via an app or system) since the last time the factory reset was done. *Data* hence corresponds to files stored in the *userdata* partition, mounted at */data*. 
 In simpler terms, *data* here is everything that would be deleted if a factory reset is performed on the device.

Comment: In what way can I flash factory images files without unlocking bootloader?I tried to flash cache partition with fastboot but it requires me to unlock bootloader...